# SQL Parameters WeekOfYear

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, date, parameters

I have this table as you can see `PreQuantity is null` 
this is because my `Week of year` parameter only looks at the weeks selected by the user so the first prequantity will be null every time.
I don't want this I want the report to look at the `week before` the users selection so that they  can see the `Prequantity @WOY = week of year = 1 to 52`

```
CREATE TABLE #salescore (
        [DivNo] NVARCHAR(max)
        ,[ProductCode] INT
        ,[Description] NVARCHAR(max)
        ,[CGNo] NVARCHAR(max)
        ,[SCGNo] NVARCHAR(max)
        ,Retail DECIMAL(38, 2)
        ,[WeekOfYear] TINYINT
        ,FirstDayOfWeek DATETIME
        ,[Quantity] INT
        ,[Sales] DECIMAL(38, 2)
        ,[NoOfStores] INT
        ,[USW] DECIMAL(38, 0)
        )

INSERT INTO #salescore
SELECT pos.DivNo
    ,pos.ProductCode
    ,[Description]
    ,[CGNo]
    ,[SCGNo]
    ,p.Retail
    ,w.WeekOfYear
    ,w.FirstDayOfWeek
    ,Sum(Quantity) [Quantity]
    ,sum(pos.Retail) [Retail2]
    ,w.NoOfStores
    ,(Sum(Quantity) / w.NoOfStores) USW
FROM .pos pos
LEFT JOIN #weeklystores w ON pos.PosDate = w.[DATETIME]
LEFT JOIN #Product p ON p.ProductCode = pos.ProductCode
    AND p.DivNo = pos.DivNo
    AND pos.DivNo = w.DivNo
WHERE pos.DivNo NOT LIKE '8__' /* Get rid of IRL Regions */
and w.Year >2013
    and w.Year IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM dbo.ufnSplit(@YEAR, ',')
        )
    AND p.EmpNo IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM dbo.ufnSplit(@BD, ',')
        )
    AND p.CGNo IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM dbo.ufnSplit(@CGNo, ',')
        )
    AND p.SCGNo IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM dbo.ufnSplit(@SCGNo, ',')
        )
    AND p.ProductClass IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM dbo.ufnSplit(@ProductClass, ',')
        )
    AND p.ProductCode IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM dbo.ufnSplit(@ProductCode, ',')
        ) 
    AND pos.DivNo IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM dbo.ufnSplit(@Region, ',')
        )
    AND w.WeekOfYear IN (
        SELECT Item
        FROM dbo.ufnSplit(@WOY, ',')
        )
    AND w.WeekOfYear IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY pos.DivNo
    ,pos.ProductCode
    ,w.WeekOfYear
    ,w.NoOfStores
    ,w.FirstDayOfWeek
    ,[Description]
    ,[CGNo]
    ,[SCGNo]
    ,p.Retail
```

[image]

Comment: As the where clause is on the LEFT JOIN table, then the left join doesn't really do anything.  You could change the query to a main table based on the filters, and then join to it a query on the .pos table to get all of the aggregated data for the records that matched the filter.

Comment: @Amir i dont particularly understand what your saying, all i need to do is have the WOY parameter 
say if the user selected the 27th week of year  the pre quantity would be null 
i need the parameter to essentially -1 and look for 26 and 27 week of years

Comment: What I meant was separate the sql into two queries. Calculate for all the weeks the Quantity and PreQuantity according to the filters on the Pos table For each DivNo regardless of the weeks the user chose. And then join that to the query over weeklyStores and Product and their filters.  If you are using Sql-Server2012, you have the Lead-Lag window functions that do just that.

Comment: @Amir ive done this but im still down to the issue of,

Comment: @Amir if the user selects week of year (WOY)1 and year = 2015 thenpart of that week falls into 2014 the report would show null for the pre quantity in week one , how can i get around this circumstance, i tried to write a case statment saying where WOY = 1 and year => datepart(YEAR,firstdayofweek) then year -1) else 0  end

Comment: @Amir this was unsuccessful as it didnt make sence